# Excel IF function and in between values, but only if

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I have values for postage, pricing and postage service (only if). I have two choices for postage service (express and eco), price depends on a weight, but service depends on a price (fast service for items over £5, eco - under).

Service: if product price(A2)

```
   <5=eco; >5=express
```

Service price(C2) by weight(B2):

```
  <=1000gr= £2 eco or £3 express
  1001-1250gr= £5 eco or £6 express
  1251-5000gr=£9 eco or £11 express
```

Cells A2 and B2 always display a value, need a formula for C2 to display the price of service calculated by weight, but if item over £5 must display express service price if less - eco.

I have tried:

```
>IF(AND(OR(B2<=1000),A2<5),2,IF(AND(OR(B2>1000,B2<=1250),A2<5),5,IF(AND(OR(B2>1250,B2<=5000),A2<5),9)))            
>IF(AND(OR(B2<=1000),A2<5),2)+IF(AND(OR(B2>=1001,B2<=1250),A2<5),5)+IF(AND(OR(B2>2000),A2<5),9)
```

Didn't start adding `A2>5`, because nothing works anyway! Tried many more, but no luck.

Would appreciate any help because stuck and ran out of options :( 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this. The preferred method is to build a small cross-reference table for your surcharges and use the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) to return the values.

However, this question was about hard-coded values in a conditional statement, so I will address that with a [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-df82ce98-edf9-46ea-8189-b0470e5e0e93) and arrayed constants.

The standard formula in C2 is,

```
=LOOKUP(B2,{0,1001,1251},{2,5,9})+SIGN(A2)*LOOKUP(B2,{0,1001,1251},{1,1,2})
```

Fill down as necessary.

In the following image, custom number formats were used on columns A and B (`[Color9]\Exp\r\e\s\s - [$£-809]#,##0.00;;[Color10]\Eco - [$£-809]#,##0.00;` and `0\g\r_)`). Weights >5000 in column B trigger a conditional formatting in column C that displays **too heavy**.

[image: lookup_mail]

Comment: Omg, thanks a lot. Can't believe that everything works, I had to add ">4.99" in +SIGN(A2)*, because service is changing depends on a product price (over £5 will be express, less than £5 will be Eco). I had to revise delivery prices depending on a product weight and price and add more delivery services so took me an extra hour but now works like a charm. I gave simple values as an example to simplify my question. Couldn't make without you, huge help. Thank you :))))) all the best ;)

Comment: This is what I got: =LOOKUP(B2,{0,501,751,1001,1251,1501,1751,2001,5001,99000},{2.28,2.28,2.28,2.62,3.19,3.19,3.79,7.95,7.95,7.95})+SIGN(A2>4.99)*LOOKUP(B2,{0,501,751,1001,1251,1501,1751,2001,5001,99000},{1.01,1.1,1.16,1.27,0.95,1.6,1.18,-2.98,0,0})  I know that it's messy, but works perfect. Thanks ones again!